# Onepage checkout update payment section on radio button click

Tags: checkout, payment, save

How can i update payment section if user click (check) radio button of payment.
So i want that magento safe the new selected payment method and reload the payment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fire payment.save() on payment method change.

Edit:
you can extend (right way) or override your opcheckout.js (in your theme)

Extended Class

```
var CustomPayment = Class.create(Payment,{
    saveAndStayOnThisStep: function(){
        if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
        var validator = new Validation(this.form);
        if (this.validate() && validator.validate()) {
            checkout.setLoadWaiting('payment');
            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method:'post',
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    // onSuccess: this.onSaveAndStay,
                    onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                    parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)
                }
            );
        }
    },
});
```

In template use CustomPayment.saveAndStayOnThisStep();

Comment: Can you show me some code? at the moment im not sure were i can set this up and who?

Comment: I try to set it here. 
onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>') , payment.save()" That works, but i want to stay at the payment section. 
If i click now it switch to the next and last step.

Comment: I update my answer with code example.